# SQL Concatenation syntax error

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using an SQL script to build the body of an email with values from a database to pass to a stored procedure, however I am getting an 'incorrect syntax near '+' error on the following line:

```
@body = 'Item number ' + @ref + 'is due calibration on ' + convert(nvarchar(20), @next) + '. <br><br>Please take the necessary action to ensure the item is calibrated before this time. <br><br>You can view the item here > http://server/app/ViewItem.aspx?calibration_no=' + @ref
```

ref is an nvarchar(50)
next is a date
body is an nvarchar(max)

Can anyone explain where i'm going wrong? Thanks!

**EDIT - Full query and procedure**

Sorry for the pastebin links, couldn't get the indentation right in the editor on here.

Query is [HERE](http://pastebin.com/10psTGXw)

Procedure is [HERE](http://pastebin.com/HmpDwdNf)

Comment: Sorry, it's an nvarchar(max). I'll edit the question

Comment: Post the whole query. This doesn't seem to have a problem.

Comment: Try printing out ref and next for the line which gives the error, or as suggested above, post more of the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you declare a variable, put the contents in the variable and then set the @Body param with that variable:

```
declare @MailBody nvarchar(max)
declare
@out_desc nvarchar(max),
@out_mesg nvarchar(50)
declare @ref nvarchar(50),
@next date
declare c1 cursor read_only
for
select [calibration_no], [description], [next_calibration]
from calibration.dbo.item
open c1
fetch next from c1 into
@ref, @next
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
if datepart(month,@next) <= dateadd(month, 1, (datepart(month, getdate())))
begin
SET @MailBody = 'Item number ' + STR(@ref) + 'is due calibration on ' + STR(convert(nvarchar(20), @next))
+ '. <br><br>Please take the necessary action to ensure the item is calibrated before this time.
<br><br>You can view the item here > http://server/app/ViewItem.aspx?calibration_no=' + STR(@ref)
exec calibration.dbo.spSendMail @recipients = 'xxxxxxxx',
@subject = 'Test Email',
@from = 'xxxxxxxx',  
@body = @MailBody
@output_mesg = @out_mesg output,
@output_desc = @out_desc output
print @out_mesg
print @out_desc
end
fetch next from c1 into
@ref, @next
end
close c1
deallocate c1
```

Comment: Thanks jyparask. Got it working now. There were a couple of other errors with the original script code I provided so I changed these bits and the full working script can now be found here > [link](http://pastebin.com/aJQsgUbB)

Answer (score 0):

To be on the safe side, I always wrap the variable with a `STR()`

This manages to avoid the incorrect syntax error

So your code would read...

```
 @body = 'Item number ' + STR(@ref) + 'is due calibration on ' + STR(convert(nvarchar(20), @next)) + '. <br><br>Please take the necessary action to ensure the item is calibrated before this time. <br><br>You can view the item here > http://server/app/ViewItem.aspx?calibration_no=' + STR(@ref)
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to do that to be honest, Mike. I'm going to expand the question as I think it may be a deeper problem than concatenation

Comment: @Jimsan - I've updated my answer to put the relevant STR() in your code

Comment: Thanks Mike, still getting the same error. Trying to post the entire script and procedure but having a 'mare copying and pasting the code. Keeps saying error posting update as it's not formatted correctly in the question box. Bare with me

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, the following worked fine for me in SQL Server:

```
declare @body nvarchar(max)
declare @ref nvarchar(50)
declare @next date

select @ref = 'test'
select @next = getdate()

select @body = 'Item number ' + @ref + 'is due calibration on ' + convert(nvarchar(20), @next) + '. <br><br>Please take the necessary action to ensure the item is calibrated before this time. <br><br>You can view the item here > http://server/app/ViewItem.aspx?calibration_no=' + @ref
select @body
```

Comment: I'm still getting the error. I will expand the question as I think it may be a deeper problem than just concatenation syntax.

Comment: Can you confirm your database platform ... SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry, yes it's SQL Server 2008 R2